# Why I'm not able to edit contents of form using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I just finished creating a signup form and I'm not able to use `display:inline-block`. I need to individually edit the contents of the form. What's wrong here?

The internal contents won't budge and everything is all together.
(also for additional tips can someone tell me different ways to center a div on the middle of the screen :)

Here's the code:
Javascript code:

```js
import React from 'react'
import './signup.css';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'

function Signp() {
  return (
    <div className='signupcontainer'>
        <form className='signup'id='signup'>
        <fieldset>
            <h1 >Sign-Up</h1>
        <section>
            <div className='FN'>First Name
            <label><input type='text' name='FNi' id='inp' required/></label></div>
            <div className='LN'>Last Name
            <label><input type='text' name='LNi' id='inp' /></label></div>
            <div>
                <label>Ph.no / E-mail</label>
                <label><input type='text' name='em/no' id='inp' pattern='[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}' required/></label> 
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>password</label>
                <label><input type='password' name='pas' id='inp' required/></label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Re-enter password</label>
                <label><input type='password' name='repas' id='inp' required/></label>
            </div>
            </section>

            <div>
                <label>Gender</label>
                <br/>
                <label><input type='radio' Name='gen'/>MALE</label>
                <label><input type='radio'Name='gen'/>FEMALE</label>
                <label><input type='radio' Name='gen' />OTHERS</label>
            </div>
            <label><input type='button' name='submit'value='Submit' required/></label>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
            <Outlet/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Signp
```

CSS code:

```css
.signupcontainer{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 80vh;
}

#signup{
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    margin: 54px;
    width: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
    align-items: center;
    
}
.signup h1{
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

#inp{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Kindly clarify your issue. What exactly are you facing and where is the exact error?

Comment: Is your question about centering a div or editing a form?

Comment: Do not use same ID. IDs must be unique in every element

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand what is the exact problem. But if you want to center the `signupcontainer` vertically and horizontally, you will need a wrapper.

Using flex:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Using grid:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

Using position:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.signupcontainer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```